# Looping through the same lines while solving puzzles

Tags: tactics, board-vision

When solving tactics sometimes I spend a lot of time (20-30 minutes) looking at the same line over and over again. 
Sometimes I have a feeling that one particular line is the right one but my vision gets blurry after 4-5 moves and I'm unable to go on without moving the piece.

Do you have any suggestions (books and/or training methods) on how to improve in this area?

Comment: What is your level/rating? That could make a difference for answering the question.

Comment: It's around 1500-1600 Elo FIDE

Comment: To clarify: are you having troubles calculating lines without physically moving the pieces?

Comment: Improving your search depth is a long and odious process that requires solving puzzles over and over. But it's usually best to finish calculating one line before moving on to the other. If you keep switching back and forth it's inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Establish an order to analyse the lines!

I would begin by the most forced moves (checks, mate threats, captures...) and finish with those where the opponent was multiple possibilities. Respect that order strictly so you won't be jumping back and forth.

Use the same criteria also for sorting subvariations (ie: start by the most obvious check, pick an opponent's answer, now calculate checks, threats and captures after that particular answer and so on)